Combinatorial Benders Cut - fastest way to find Irreducible Infeasible Subsystems (IIS)
I reformulated a VRP problem via combinatorial Benders Decomposition, moving all Big-M constraints to the Linear program (LP) sub problem.
I implemented the Benders approach in Gurobi, if I find an incumbent solution in the Master problem (MP), I check if the LP is infeasible. If it is infeasible, I compute via the Gurobi-function model.computeIIS() the minimum Irreducible Infeasible Subsystems (IIS).
For the IIS set $IIS_X$, I create a feasibility cut of the form $\sum_{e \in IIS_x} x_{e} \leq |IIS_X|-1$, to cut off the infeasible solution in the master problem for my binary decision variable $x_{e} \in \{0,1\}$ and add it via a lazy constraint.
The function model.computeIIS() is quite fast, and my Benders approach outperforms the standard model with Gurobi. But I read in the paper by Codato & Fischetti (2006), that it is beneficial to use the Dual-Primal relationship for a faster IIS-Search. I implemented a second version, which selects the set $IIS_X$ based on the constraints, for which the Farkas Dual value of the subproblem LP constraint is positive, but this version generates more lazy constraints and is slower than my first approach.
My question is, if there are any speed-up techniques to use? Should I work directly with the dual LP subproblem or is it okay, to query the Farkas Dual from the Primal LP? Is there any benefit? It seems that I miss something and would be happy for any insights, some can give me into this topic.
Codato, Gianni; Fischetti, Matteo (2006): Combinatorial Benders' Cuts for Mixed-Integer Linear Programming. In Operations Research 54 (4), pp. 756–766. DOI: 10.1287/opre.1060.0286.
EDIT: I also heard that to speed up, it makes sense to add feasbility cuts as user cuts for fractional solutions. But I am not sure how I can use this approach to cut off fractional solutions, because I need to treat the fractional values as integer to construct the subproblem LP or do I get it wrong?

I think that either way of finding an IIS should work in principle. Both Gurobi's computeIIS and the approach based on the Farkas ray from the paper attempt to find a sparse IIS, so that the no-good cut added will have few terms in it. Maybe the Farkas ray approach works better, because it specifically targets the big-M constraints, rather than small conflicts in general?
As for your question about fractional values, I'm not sure how this would be done, as you need an integer-feasible solution in order to build the subproblem, right?

Thank you for your reply! Regarding the fractional values, this is what I am struggling to understand right now. I am first checking for subtour elemination constraint (SEC) separation and add a SEC cut if possible, else a combinatorial Benders cut. As far as I understood, one can separate fractional solutions for SEC by solving multiple mincut problems? Of course, this is a tradeoff between number of cuts added and running time. As I understood, it should be also possible for Benders cuts? But of course, for my approach I need an integer feasible solution to make it work.

Yes, in general, one generates cuts to separate also fractional solutions. It's just for this special case of Combinatorial Benders that I didn't see how the subproblem (for which we find the IIS) would be defined, because I thought only the "active" big-M constraints would be included, and the rest dropped.
I've just looked into the paper again and now I see that they use fractional x values to defined weights (1 - x) for the constraints, and then look for a weighted IIS.
